# Inset boundary hot key in blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling

I am working on anvil by blender guru tutorial but inset boundary is not working in Blender 2.8. what is the shortcut in 2.8?

Comment: Could you specify which part of the tutorial series? Inset face is still "I". "B" toggles the Boundary on and off. I did find a post about the anvil tutorial talking about problems with the inset boundary here: https://blenderartists.org/t/boundary-not-affecting-mirrored-portions-of-my-model/701549

Comment: demo from Imphenzia in 2.8/2.8 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8&t=1056s

Answer (score 4):

After hitting <kbd>I</kbd> key, continue with the <kbd>B</kbd> key to turn off/on boundary feature.

Answer (score 3):

I watched the video and had the same issue. What solved it for me was that you have to delete the face/s that is "in" the mirror, eg facing each other. In the tutorial by Blender Guru he does that early in the modelling.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Asking for keybinds on SE are a little wobbly since they can be changed by both preference and what kind of layout you chose, but the best way to find out a keybind is to press <kbd>F3</kbd> (or <kbd>spacbar</kbd> if you chose it to be that way) to bring up the action search.  This will also show the keyboard shortcut if one is set.

[image]

Now, as for "Inset Border"... I'm not sure what that is.  Do you mean Bevel?  That is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. There is also "Inset Faces", which is kind of like extrude but scaling the faces instead.

Comment: He might mean the *toggle Boundary mode* while inset operator running.